# Facebook feed plugin is not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this facebook feed script on my site, but on mobile the height isnt responsive, how to make it responsive if i dont have access to that script? I have only this in my html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://feed.mikle.com/js/fw-loader.js" 
data-fw-param="47031/"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use Facebooks own plugin's

https://developers.facebook.com/products/social-plugins/embeds/

Those are responsive and always up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Simply look at the HTML, target it and change the CSS for it. Same as any other HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The JS is taking pre-determined styles set by that site [feed.mikle.com](https://feed.mikle.com/). So, to change the style you would have to get into that style sheet. Since you're not creating the feed yourself (and using something someone else created) you're likely at the mercy of their setup. Perhaps you can contact their support team to find out your options.